# How to filter weekday of datetime in model filter?

Tags: python, django

For example, I can filter month of datetime like this: ExampleModel.objects.filter(createtime__month=month), because month is a field of datetime
, but weekday is a built-in function of datetime, so how to filter weekday of datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has a lookup for weekdays, see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day):

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__week_day=2)
```

Comment: Yeah, it's right. By the way, how to filter time of datetime, by hour, minutes and second of datetime?

Comment: `pub_date__hour`, `pub_date__minute` and `pub_date__second`. You have this info in the link that schneck provided to you